# google cloud compute engine change to python 3.6

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am a running a python script where I train CNN on my laptop and now want to run it on google cloud. The script imports tensorflow and keras, for which I need Python 3.6

The steps I followed were:

1. Go to compute engine and create a virtual machine with 8cpus
2. I ssh into the virtual machine, and I see that the python version is 2.7

How can I change the python version to 3.6 so I can install keras, and then to be able to run my python script?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Try `python3`, and use `pip3` to install packages for Python3.

Comment: @Deqing  :  But how can I change to python3 ?

Comment: If there is no Python3 in your VM, install it. If you'd like the command `python` to use Python3, google `virtualenv`

Comment: I have python3 installed but its 3.5.3. I can't seem to get it to upgrade to 3.6. Tried sudo apt-get install python3.6 but didn't do anything.

Comment: This link has an answer that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399762/how-do-i-install-python-3-on-google-cloud-console

Comment: This link worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399762/how-do-i-install-python-3-on-google-cloud-console

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. By preference, I cd'ed into /tmp: cd /tmp, but from there, I followed these steps in the VM terminal:

1. wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
2. tar -xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz
3. cd Python-3.6.3
4. ./configure
5. sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
6. sudo make
7. sudo make install
8. python3 -V

If it works, the last one should print out: 
Python 3.6.3

If it doesn't work, then you have something different about your environment that is preventing it.  This is starting from a clean VM environment.  But hopefully this works out for you!

Comment: I had to install a C compiler and make also: `apt install gcc make`

Comment: this installation works well for python3.6 install but fails while installation of packages in pip3.6 with SSL error

Comment: @BrB You have to make sure SSL libraries are installed (```sudo apt-get install libssl-dev```) prior to compiling python3.6 (also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250324/1134841)

Answer (score -1):

You can install it by using:

```
sudo apt-get -y -qq install python3
```

Check this using:

```
python3 --version
```