# WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip

I would like to use Python3.8.x on Google Cloud Compute Engine.

First, I created an instance with `gcloud` command.

```
gcloud compute instances create \
  pegasus-test \
  --zone=asia-northeast1-b \
  --machine-type=n1-highmem-8 \
  --boot-disk-size=500GB \
  --image-project=ml-images \
  --image-family=tf-1-15 \
  --maintenance-policy TERMINATE --restart-on-failure
```

In default, Python version is 3.5.3.

```
python3 -V
Python 3.5.3
```

Therefore, I upgraded Python. I followed this instruction. ([google cloud compute engine change to python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273260/google-cloud-compute-engine-change-to-python-3-6))

```
cd /tmp
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.3/Python-3.8.3.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.8.3.tgz
cd Python-3.8.3
./configure
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo make
sudo make install
```

I got no error message.
Now, I have Python3.8.3.

```
python3 -V
Python 3.8.3
```

Next, I would like to use PEGASUS. (https://github.com/google-research/pegasus)

```
git clone https://github.com/google-research/pegasus
cd pegasus
export PYTHONPATH=.
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Then, I got an error message.

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting absl-py (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("
Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("
Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("
Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("
Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("
Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/absl-py/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/absl-py/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(
host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/absl-py/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL beca
use the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement absl-py (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: non
e)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for absl-py (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='
pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I checked pip's version.

```
pip3 -V
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

So, I tried to upgrade pip. `pip3 install --upgrade pip` Then, I got this error message.

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Ca
n't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Ca
n't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Ca
n't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Ca
n't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Ca
n't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='
pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='
pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SS
L module is not available.")) - skipping
```

So, next I used `pip` instead of `pip3`. I input `pip install -r requirements.txt`

This is the result.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mock in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 3)) (1.16.6)
Collecting rouge-score
  Downloading rouge_score-0.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting sacrebleu
  Downloading sacrebleu-1.3.7.tar.gz (26 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/setup.p
y'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f
.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/
pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/setup.py", line 65, in <module>
        version = get_version(),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-HCHhuX/sacrebleu/setup.py", line 56, in get_version
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sacrebleu.py'), encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

How can I realize `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`? Could you give me any advice, please?

Comment: pip apparently uses your python2.7 installation, which isn't what you want.  Also, does your python3 recognize the ssl module?  what happens if you type ```python3 -c 'import ssl'```?

Comment: @VivakP Thank you very much for your answer. When I type `python3 -c 'import ssl'` , I get `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'` Could you tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to spend a few days to tackle.
After exploring many different solutions, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62264725/13699929) worked for the pip ssl issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution worked for my problem, too!

Answer (score 4):

Resolved this on windows 10 by installing openssl

[used this link](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)